# Display Deal Page for non-admin (.i.e. standard visitors) with Rails 4/Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm developing a Daily deal app on ruby on Rails to learn it.

I have installed active admin to **create as admin**, Users and Deals.
It's working great but what I don't understand (as I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails), is:

Does Active Admin generate on its own the routes for Deals so that I already would have at my disposal for each deals like: myapp.com/deals/deal_id=456 (deal 456) ? It would be a page describing the deal n° 456 ?

I see if I do 'rake routes' that I have the following route that has been created by Active Admin: myapp/admin/deals/:id which is my view page of the Deal on Active Admin, but that's not what i want to do. I want to display a view for the website visitors for the Deal. It should be on something like myapp.com/deals/456

I need to be able to AUTOMATICALLY create a route/url (such as myapp.com/deals/456) that web visitors can see as soon i create the Deal in my admin interface on Active Admin.

Should I just create a 'show' method on the DealsController ?

How to manage the generate a 'route/url' part every time I create a new Deal in my admin interface on Active Admin ?

If you know of any web resource explaining this, that would be appreciated too as I am a newbie (note that I could also use guidelines for: a blog it would be how to generate the route/url to display a certain blog post after creating it on AA,  or for a ecommerce website it would be to create the route/url for a Product Page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails basics then:

`:id` stands for the value of the id column of the model you are viewing/editing/handling/whatever.

So, if you want your route to respond to

```
/deals/deal_456
```

You have to instruct it to do exactly that:

```
match '/deals/deal_:id', to: "deals#show", via: 'get', as: :view_deal # or path of your like
```

Then, all the below will be equivalent, in terms of what you see

```
@deal=Deal.find(456)
redirect_to view_deal_path(@deal) # myapp.com/deals/deal_456
redirect_to deal_path(@deal) # myapp.com/deals/456
redirect_to @deal # myapp.com/deals/456
```

Comment: Thanks but what i need is to automatically generate this route each time i create in active admin a Deal. Its like a blog on rails/active amdin, you don't want to go to your routeS.rb to create a route each time you create a blog post. I need to automate the url/route creation.

Comment: routes.rb is generic, it's not per instance. It's per class. You create each route once and you only change the parameters that point to your instance. What you refer to as route is an instance uri

Comment: So, let the magic begin... You are going to love rails once you learn around it